# Test web services in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to check how much response time  of a web service .Suppose a web service is being hit by 10000 users at same time so how much time it is taking both on local and production. I need to check for both get and post request.I have look on internet but I am getting jmeter which I think is for java.Can anyone suggest me tools for rails.

Comment: there is a ruby version of JMeter ([`ruby-jmeter`](https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter)) and seems to be generally recommended for load testing (lots of tutorials). There are also other load testing tools available like [`blitz`](https://www.blitz.io/docs/ruby-gem#/) and [loader.io](https://loader.io/). **I am not promoting any of these tools as I have not used them but feel free to give it a shot.**

Comment: jmeter is written in Java but you can use it to test any web page / service. I can only recommend it. It's a powerful tool.

Comment: okay thx for the advice i will give it a try

Comment: I have actually used loader.io for testing my web services

Answer (score 0):

Try [blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/). There are some restrictions on free tests but still it may help. Additionally maybe you can use native ruby benchmark command.